# Why does the hard-looking double integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)y(1+y)}{(1-xy)\ln(xy)}dxdy=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: integration

(1) originate from [here problem 11322](http://home.earthlink.net/~jsondow/)

(1)

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)y(1+y)}{(1-xy)\ln(xy)}dxdy=-\frac{1}{2}$$

On my recent post see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798467/why-does-the-hard-looking-integral-int-0-infty-fracx-sin2x-coshx) Marco Cantarini and hints from other proved the hard-looking integral.

We manage to find another hard-looking double integral type that yield simple answer via wolfram integrator.

Can anyone help us to prove (1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we perform a change of variables $x=e^{-u},y=e^{-v}$ we may easily check that

$$J(a,b) = \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x^a y^b}{\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = -\frac{1}{a-b}\,\log\left(\frac{1+a}{1+b}\right) \tag{1}$$
from which it follows that
$$\begin{eqnarray*}K(a,b) &=& \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x^a y^b(1-x)(1+y)}{\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy\\ &=& \frac{\log\left(\frac{2+a}{1+b}\right)}{1+a-b}+\frac{\log\left(\frac{1+a}{2+b}\right)}{1+b-a}+\frac{\log\left(\frac{2+a}{2+b}\right)-\log\left(\frac{1+a}{1+b}\right)}{a-b} \tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and by letting $b\to a$
$$ H(a) = \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x^a y^a(1-x)(1+y)}{\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = \frac{1}{2+a}-\frac{1}{1+a}\tag{3}$$
so, just like in the other problem, the original integral is related with a telescopic series:

> $$\begin{eqnarray*}I=\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{xy}{1-xy}\cdot\frac{(1-x)(1+y)}{\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy &=& \sum_{n\geq 1} H(n) \\ &=& -\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{4}\end{eqnarray*} $$

as wanted. The only non-trivial step is $(1)$, that follows from [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

There is also a symmetry trick. By exchanging $x$ and $y$ in the original integral and considering the arithmetic mean of the two integrals we get:

$$I=\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{xy}{\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = J(1,1) = -\left.\frac{d}{dz}\log(z+1)\right|_{z=1} = \color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: I think we may also reverse-engineer Sondow's thoughts: start with a telescopic series $\sum a_n = \sum (b_n-b_{n+1})$ and write $a_n$ as an integral like $\int z^n f(z)\,dz$ (through the Laplace/Mellin transform, for instance). Then $\int\frac{z^m f(z)}{1-z}\,dz $ has a very good chance to be a horrible integral, but it has for sure a very nice closed form.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the way you tackle this problem as if it is a $1+1$ problem. Thank you. Very nice!

Comment: +1. Very nice job. The result $\left(1\right)$ is straightforward with the identity:
$$
{1 \over \ln\left(xy\right)} = -\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(xy\right)^{t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$