# Roots of $\cos{x}+\cosh^2{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, exponential-function, roots, hyperbolic-functions

I wanted to find the roots of $\cos{x}+\cosh^2{x}=0$ to solve an [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154378/evaluating-a-polynomic-trigonometric-hyperbolic-integral) with this expression in the denominator. I started by using the exponential definitions of the cosine function and its hyperbolic counterpart. At first, I tried substituting $v=e^x$ and I got the following equation
$$v^2+v^{-2}+2v^i+2v^{-i}=-2$$
I don't know how to proceed because of the complex exponents.

For my second try, I reduced the equation into the following.
$$e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}+1)=0$$
Multiply both sides by $e^{2x}e^{ix}$
$$(e^{4x}+1)e^{ix}+2e^{2x}(e^{2ix}+e^{ix}+1)=0$$
Replace $e^x$ with $a$ and $e^{ix}$ with $b$
$$(a^4+1)b+2a^2(b^2+b+1)=0$$
After some manipulation we get the following system
$$\frac{b}
{b^2+b+1}=\frac{-2a^2}{a^4+1}$$
$$a^i=b$$
It sure is elegant, but I don't know how to continue after this. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=cosx%2Bcosh%5E2x%3D0%20roots) gives 4 roots. Interestingly enough, they're all conjugates and negatives of each other.
I want a closed form for these roots

Comment: Why use $a$ and $b$ when all you need is $a$ since $b=a^i$?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson That's what I tried first. It's in the question

Comment: @chroma There are infinite roots as seen in [this graph](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#(cos(z)%2Bcosh(z)%5E2))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to find the roots of

$$f(x) = \cos(x) + \cosh^2(x) = 0$$

A plot shows there are no real roots (prove this), so we'll use imaginary initial conditions.

Let's try a numerical method like [*Newton's Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

We have the iteration formula

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \dfrac{\cos(x_n) + \cosh^2(x_n)}{-\sin(x_n) + 2 \sinh(x_n) \cosh(x_n)}$$

Taking

- $x_0 = 1 + i$
- $x_1 = 0.98133 + 1.21656i$
- $x_2 = 1.02262 + 1.19678i$
- $x_3 = 1.02194 + 1.19864i$
- $x_4 = 1.02195 + 1.19864i$
- $x_5 = 1.02195 + 1.19864i$

We converge to one of the roots in five steps.

Next, we can try the additional initial points for the other roots

$$x_0 = 1 - i, -1 + i, -1 - i$$

This produces the other three roots, and we are not always so lucky!

We can visualize these four roots as

[image]

We can also draw a complex plot to try and ascertain the behavior of roots and to give insight for more roots. Using Mathematica's [*ComplexPlot*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html), we see (refer to link for meaning of colors)

[image]

Here is another variation of the command

[image]

Comment: How do you know there aren't more than four roots?

Comment: @mr_e_man: That is a very good point. In the imaginary world with trig functions, you can likely find an infinite number of roots. If I expand the ranges for roots, I can find more and more roots, however, I based this on the Wolfram Alpha roots shown in the OP with no more analysis.

Comment: @mr_e_man: After some more graphical investigations (see updates in color pictures), I think the four roots are good, but this is still not proof. At a zero or a pole $f(z)$ behaves like $z^m$ (after shifting to the position of the pole or zero) and so $r^me^{mit}$ and thus as an oscillator with frequency $m$. That has the advantage that it also shows the multiplicity of the zero or pole.

Comment: (+1) I like this answer. I was looking for a closed form but this is great too

Comment: I just use `FindRoot[{A==0,B==0},{a,1},{b,1}]` In my opinion, it is much easier than with the complex. The same for the plots (my wife explains me how they look). Cheers :-)

Comment: That worked great. Try this (change the $-1$ to a $-2$ or $-3$) to see the differences. ContourPlot[(Cosh[2*a]*Cos[2*b] + 2*Cos[a]*Cosh[b] + 
     1)^2 + (Sinh[2*a]*Sin[2*b] - 2*Sin[a]*Sinh[b])^2 - 1, {a, -1.59, 
  1.59}, {b, -1.59, 1.59}]. Does that work? I think it aligns with the other plots.

Comment: YYou are right for sure. The plot you suggest seems to be very beautiful (according to my wife who does understand (at all) what we are speaking about. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Three contour plots added to your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

*Another approach since @Moo already gave the answer.*

If you let $x=a+ib$, you need to solve
$$A=\cosh (2 a) \cos (2 b)+2 \cos (a) \cosh (b)+1$$
$$B=\sinh (2 a) \sin (2 b)-2\sin (a) \sinh (b)$$

The contour plot of $A^2+B^2$

[image]

**Edit**

The values are
$$a=\pm 1.0219475008555489912136043745628796474210493455454\cdots$$
$$b=\pm 1.1986441687060052054821382505580638278740838448344\cdots$$

Surprising (thanks to the $ISC$ !) is that $b$ is very close to the largest real root of
$$x^{12}-x^{11}+x^{10}-x^9+x^8-x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3-x^2-x+1=0$$ The absolute difference is $4.79\times 10^{-8}$.

Another good approximation is $\Re\left(\sqrt[7]{-5-3 i}\right)$

Comment: (+1). What is ISC?

Comment: @Moo. **I**nverse **S**ymbolic **C**alculator   http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html   Enjoy it